# Can I solve x+3=7; x=7?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Basically, I’m arguing with someone if there’s a chance that $x+3=7$ and $x=7$ can be solved.
I know I did learn in school that basically any equation can be solved with the right formulas.

Comment: This is unclear. Solved separately or simultaneously?  Let's start there.

Comment: Simultanously, basicly, x+3=7 and x is declared as 7, can it be solved?

Comment: If $x=7$, then $x+3=10$; $x=7$ and $x+3=7$ are inconsistent

Comment: If you are asking for what value of $x$ makes it so that simultaneously $x+3=7$ and $x=7$ are both true., there doesn't exist any such value of $x$ (*assuming we're talking about working in the usual real number system*).  It is called an "*Inconsistent System of Equations.*"  The first equation would have required $x$ to be equal to $4$ while the second would have required that $x$ would be equal to $7$.  Since these two things contradict one another and cannot occur simultaneously, we learn that there does *not* exist a solution to the system.

Comment: I suggest reading more about systems of equations in the article on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Consistency) and in particular the section on *consistency*.

Comment: Don't believe everything you learn in school.

Comment: As an aside... "*basically any equation can be solved with the right formulas*"... there are some questions that we can ask for which no formula exists... not even just that no *known* formula exists in some cases but rather that it is known that no formula could possibly exist.

Comment: I got it, i did learn in school that anything can be solved with The right formula. JMoravitz, well put, thank you for your time, have a nice night

Comment: I think there are two possible meanings of "solved" here: first, and technically what mathematicians usually mean, "Produce at least one (more, if they exist) solution to this system of equations" ; second, what your teacher and/or classmates probably meant in school, "Solve the problem: what are the solutions (if they exist) to this system of equations?" You can do either, we just have to remember they're different in this case!

Answer (score 2):

Assume there exists some number $x$ such that $x=7$ and $x+3 = 7$, where $3$ and $7$ have their usual meaning as real numbers.

Then since $x=7$ by the first equation, we can substitute $7$ for $x$ in the second equation and we get $10 = 7$. This is not true for any value of $x$. This contradicts our assumption (which was that such an $x$ exists). So your system of equations has **no solution**.

---

Note that there are nonstandard "number systems" which contain values $\overline{3}$ and $\overline{7}$ that behave similarly to how $3$ and $7$ behave in the integers. An example would be the finite field $\mathbb F_3$, where $\overline 3$ and $\overline 7$ are the images of $3$ and $7$ under the unique ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb F_3$. In this field, it is true that $a + \overline 3 = a$ for all $a$ in $\mathbb F_3$, so if we choose $x := \overline 7$, we find that $x = \overline 7$ and $x + \overline 3 = \overline 7$. In fact, $\overline 7$ is the unique solution for this system of linear equations in $x$.

But even though I've just showed you a mathematical situation where this is possible, you should be very cautious to accept this as a solution to your system of equations if it occurs in any practical context, because the number system $\mathbb F_3$ is very different from your usual numbers. In fact, it contains only exactly three numbers: $\overline 3$, $\overline 7$ and $\overline 7 + \overline 7$. This number system is pretty much incompatible with regular numbers you know from school: for example $\overline 7 + \overline 7 = \overline 3 - \overline 7$ and $\overline 7 \div (\overline 7+\overline 7) = \overline 7+\overline 7$. These things are simply wrong if you replace $\overline 3$ and $\overline 7$ by regular $3$ and $7$. The remainder class $\overline 7$ is an analogue of $7$, but still a completely different mathematical object: $7 \neq \overline 7$. So there's **still no solution** to the system of real equations $x=7$ and $x+3 = 7$.

You might also notice that I've used some terms you don't know about, like "[finite field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field)" and "[ring homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_homomorphism)". These terms (as well as the Wikipedia pages I linked) are entry-level university maths, you're pretty certain not to see them taught in school. If you like, you can look into some linear algebra courses to learn what these things are about.